# How many cones pass through a given conic section?

Tags: conic-sections, projective-geometry

Given a conic section in the $xy$-plane, how many cones (infinite double cone) in the surrounding 3D space intersect the $xy$-plane at that conic? Is the family continuous, with a nice parametization?

At least one must exist, and I expect symmetry in the conic to give a few such cones by reflection, but are there more than that?

**Edit:**
Following Peter Smith's answer, it seems possible that a continuum of such cones exist. If that were to be the case, what is the locus of the apexes of those cones?

Comment: What do you mean by _cone_ here ?

Comment: I mean the double infinite cone, or a locus of lines passing through a given $p$ and forming a given angle $\theta$ to a given line. I hope that was self-evident enough.

Comment: Therefore you mean a right circular cone.

Comment: Yes, it's correct. I think it's the default meaning of "cone" when discussing conic sections.

Comment: Your edit seems well-founded: every quadric cone is circular (Apollonius, Desargues, etc.) but, in general, not right.

Answer (score 1):

To take the simplest case, take the circle to be centred at $(0, 0, 0)$ in the $xy$-plane; and now take any point $(0, 0, z)$. Then plainly there is a double cone of rays which pass through $(0, 0, z)$ and some point on the circle (and this is a right circular cone). So there are continuum-many distinct such cones (i.e. as many as there are are points $(0, 0, z)$) which have the given circle as section in the $xy$-plane. [This observation generalizes, mutatis mutandis, to other sorts of conic section: you'll get continuum-many possibilities.]

Comment: I don't think it's so obvious that the observation generalizes to other conics. Even if it does, what is the locus of the apexes of the cones?